# Controlling nuisance covariate in lmer

Tags: r, mixed-model, ancova

I want to control for a nuisance covariate in a linear model. Since the covariate interacts significantly with one of the fixed factors, the homogeneity of regression slopes assumption is violated for an ANCOVA approach. My understanding is that this can be handled in a multi-level, or mixed effects, model.

My data:

```
> str(seeds)
'data.frame':   186 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ fixed.A : Factor w/ 31 levels "A1","A2","A3",..: 7 7 7 7 7 7 10 10 10 10 ...
     $ fixed.B : Factor w/ 2 levels "Y","N": 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ cov     : num  10.3 10.5 11 12.8 12.9 ...
     $ response: num  10.8 11 11.1 14.7 15.3 ...
```

The covariate `cov` has a significant interaction with `fixed.A`. To fit a random intercept and slope for `cov` conditioned on `fixed.A`, it seems an approach using `lmer` (in lme4) might be:

```
> lmer(response ~ fixed.A*fixed.B + (1 + cov | fixed.A), data = seeds)
```

I'm aware that this is not the usual approach in `lmer` since grouping factors tend to be random and therefore don't also appear as fixed factors in the model formula. However, since I'm interested in the interaction between my two fixed factors, I don't see how else to proceed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: this model is unidentifiable.  You *might* want `response~1+Fixed.A*fixed.B + (0 + cov|fixed.A)` ... ?

Comment: @Ben Thanks, you're right. Does the formula you propose fit a single intercept for the model with varying slopes for the covariate? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model,

```
response ~ fixed.A*fixed.B + (1 + cov | fixed.A)
```

translates to

$$
\begin{split}
y_{ijk} & \sim \textrm{N}(\mu_{ijk},\sigma^2_r) \\
\mu_{ijk} & = \beta_{ij} + b_{i1} + b_{i2} x_{ijk} \\
(b_{i1}, b_{i2}) & \sim \textrm{MVN}(\boldsymbol 0,\Sigma(\boldsymbol \theta))
\end{split}
$$

The problem is that some of the $\beta_{ij}$ parameters and the $b_{i1}$ parameters are jointly unidentifiable.

If you instead use

```
response~fixed.A*fixed.B + cov + (0 + cov|fixed.A)
```

you eliminate the random intercept and get

$$
\begin{split}
y_{ijk} & \sim \textrm{N}(\mu_{ijk},\sigma^2_r) \\
\mu_{ijk} & = \beta_{ij} + \beta_x x_{ijk} + b_{i2} x_{ijk} \\
b_{i2} & \sim \textrm{N}(0,\theta^2)
\end{split}
$$

(For a sensible model you need to include an overall fixed effect of $x$ (`cov`), because the random effects are zero-centered.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. When you say x, do you mean cov?

Comment: @Ben Bolker, I was hoping you could assist me in a related question. My [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/387225/adding-nuisance-covariates-to-mixed-model?noredirect=1&lq=1) was marked as duplicate of this one, but I still don't understand how to apply your solution to my specific problem. If I have only a random intercept model, where would I place the covariate? I do not want to eliminate the random intercept and I don't model random slopes, so how would the syntax be in my case?